# How do I filter json-rpc requests using stuff like wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, json-rpc

I've been trying to filter my requests using wireshark but so far to no avail. I already know how to filter xml-rpc requests using wireshark. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.icodeya.com/2014/07/using-wireshark-to-filter-http-requests.html). I trust that to filter json-rpc requests, I should also follow a similar route? I tried to replace the xml filter to json and I also tried http, but I don't get anything at all. Sometimes, I do get something but they're a bunch of ok/200 responses and they dont even resemble any of the actual response I get. How to properly get the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with wireshark. This [link](http://acataleptii.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-capture-json-rpc-traffic-using.html) covers it, complete with screenshots. It is under `statistics> conversations list> TCP`, send your request, then click on follow stream.